ThisLRPositionWallPaper VS ThisLRCornerWallpaper. How do they actually work?
According to wallpapermanual.pdf (ver1.30) in this link
https://www.cs.rug.nl/~michael/wallpapermanual.pdf, we can move the image around at the corner.
Here is the example:
\ThisLRPositionWallPaper{<scaling>}{x-offset}{y-offset}{<filename>}

We should be able to move the image at the right corner at the bottom of the page horizontally by x unit and vertically by y units.
I use wallpaper and watermark to place the image at the corner. The following code works perfectly
\rightwatermark{\ThisLRCornerWallPaper{0.75}{image.png}}

However, I still want to move the image a little bit further by using the above code they provide in the manual.
\rightwatermark{\ThisLLPositionWallPaper{0.75}{1cm}{2cm}{image.png}}

I try to play around with this but it doesn't seem to work at all. Could anyone explain how it works or give an example of code? Thanks in advance.
Here is the code :
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{article}

\usepackage[top=1in, bottom=1in]{geometry}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{everyshi,eso-pic,calc,settobox}


\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{watermark}
\usepackage{wallpaper}
\rightwatermark{\ThisLRCornerWallPaper{0.35}{example-image-a}}
\leftwatermark{\ThisLLCornerWallPaper{0.35}{example-image-b}}

\usepackage{anyfontsize}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-15]

\end{document}

The picture are at the corner as desired but I want to move them to the right(or left) and down a little bit further. Which code should I use?

Welcome! Can you provide the code for a minimal example we can compile to reproduce the issue? You can probably substitute an image from the mwe collection for the actual watermark (unless it is text, of course) e.g. \includegraphics{example-image-a} will work for everybody. (It will make for a strange and ugly 'watermark' but it will compile.)

The manual you linked appears to be for a later version of the package than the one on CTAN (https://www.ctan.org/pkg/wallpaper). Can you reproduce with version 1.10? If not can you tell us where you got version 1.30 of the package from? Most people will have 1.10 as that's the one in all the distributions. Every TeX distribution gets its stuff from CTAN either directly or indirectly. If version 1.10 doesn't have the issue and does what you want, version 1.30 may be a version which never made it to CTAN for good reason, though that's not obvious from the docs.

@cfr I provide the code and the manual can be found online.
\ThisLLPositionWallPaper{0.75}{1cm}{2cm}{image.png}
The above code is found only in the later version 1.30.

Well, everyshi is obsolete. How old is your TeX installation? It became obsolete in 2020. What does not working mean?

I can't try with \ThisLRPositionWallPaper because I don't have a copy of version 1.30 of the package. The version I have is the one on CTAN and that doesn't provide that command at all. So you need to tell us where you got your copy of wallpaper.sty from as it is not the distributed one.

@cfr I use everyshi package because it is said to install if you want to use wallpaper package at the end of the manual.

@cfr I google the wallpaper package and I found it online in the above URL. I haven't checked it on CTAN.

That means wallpaper requires it and will load it itself. The same for eso-pic etc. How old is your TeX distribution? If you have a current version of LaTeX, I would avoid using watermark and probably wallpaper, but wallpaper is high-level enough it will probably work OK. watermark is adding stuff in the page header and then wallpaper is pushing it into hooks via eso-pic which run when the page ships out. On current LaTeX, it would be better to use the kernel's shipout hooks. On older LaTeX, obviously you can't.

That URL is for the manual (.pdf) but you must have a .sty as well. Where did you get the .sty file? Does the code you posted give an error? Or does it just not give the output you expected?

The code I provide doesn't give me any error but the output is not what I expected, I want to move the pic down more and also push it to the right. Basically, I don't to see the whole picture. I need some part of the pic to be off the page.

Please tell us which TeX distribution you have and which version. For example, TeX Live 2024 or MacTeX 2023 or whatever. LaTeX has changed since some of these packages were written. We can't help you effectively if we don't know what software you're using.

Oh sorry I forgot to tell you that. I use overleaf to run the code.
